# Display gnuplot default line styles

Tags: colors, gnuplot

How can I show gnuplot's default line styles (for a given output terminal)?

I see that if I define my own line style, I can show it. But it doesn't show the specification of the default styles as displayed by the `test` command.

```
gnuplot> show style line

gnuplot> set style line 44 lt 2 lc rgb "green" lw 2
gnuplot> show style line
        linestyle 44,  linetype 2 linecolor rgb "green"  linewidth 2.000 pointtype 2 pointsize default pointinterval 0
```

I'd like to see the specification of the default line style colors so that I can use corresponding colors in the web page that will include my plot.

Note that I am not asking "how do I draw a particular line style", or "how do I graphically display what the line styles look like" (test command). I am asking how to list the (text) description of default line styles.

Comment: With version 4.6 you cannot use `show` to display the definition of the default `linetype`. (with the upcoming 5.0 you can). If you need the colors for a special terminal, you need other ways to get the color.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With gnuplot version 5 the command `show linetype 1` gives you the definition of the first default linetype.

```
gnuplot> show linetype 1

    linetype 1,  linecolor rgb "dark-violet"  linewidth 1.000 dashtype solid pointtype 1 pointsize default pointinterval 0
```

And with `show linetypes` you a list of all predefined linetypes:

```
gnuplot> show linetypes

    linetype 1,  linecolor rgb "dark-violet"  linewidth 1.000 dashtype solid pointtype 1 pointsize default pointinterval 0
    linetype 2,  linecolor rgb "#009e73"  linewidth 1.000 dashtype solid pointtype 2 pointsize default pointinterval 0
    linetype 3,  linecolor rgb "#56b4e9"  linewidth 1.000 dashtype solid pointtype 3 pointsize default pointinterval 0
    linetype 4,  linecolor rgb "#e69f00"  linewidth 1.000 dashtype solid pointtype 4 pointsize default pointinterval 0
    linetype 5,  linecolor rgb "#f0e442"  linewidth 1.000 dashtype solid pointtype 5 pointsize default pointinterval 0
    linetype 6,  linecolor rgb "#0072b2"  linewidth 1.000 dashtype solid pointtype 6 pointsize default pointinterval 0
    linetype 7,  linecolor rgb "#e51e10"  linewidth 1.000 dashtype solid pointtype 7 pointsize default pointinterval 0
    linetype 8,  linecolor rgb "black"  linewidth 1.000 dashtype solid pointtype 8 pointsize default pointinterval 0
    Linetypes repeat every 8 unless explicitly defined
```

Comment: Why does `show linetype 0` give an error 'tag must be > zero' when linetype 0 is a grey dotted line, as shown by the `test` command?

Answer (score 2):

You can see them (visually) by using `test` command.
From [documentation](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node237.html) (v 4.2):

"Each terminal has a default set of line and point types, which can be seen by using the command `test`".